# Delete "else" token appearing for Eclipse Compiler

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

So, I've been trying to read through "Java for Dummies", and one of their sample projects is creating a very simple, and drafted Username/Password Login. I typed the same thing in, tried to make sense of it, but I noticed that there was an error, saying to delete my "else" token. My code makes sense to me, but I think that I did something wrong. Please help me out with this! Here is my code.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Usernames {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String Username = 
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Username: ");

        String Password =
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Password: ");

         if (Username != null && Password != null &&
              Username.equals("KnotALun") && Password.equals("spade4600"));
         { 
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
             (null, "You're in!!!");
         }

//This is the "else" command that the compiler wants me to delete.

         else{
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
             (null, "Incorrect Username or Password :(");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of your if statement

Comment: Care to fix your indentation?

Answer (score 4):

Remove the semicolon at the end of

```
(Username.equals("KnotALun") && Password.equals("spade4600"))));
```

This effectively terminates the `if` statement and the complier complains about the `else` keyword as it cannot find any corresponding `if` statement for it.